# react navigation: Navigate to screen from specific screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My navigation structure looks something like this:

```
    TabNavigator
    |
    |- StackNavigator
    |  |
    |  |- ListA
    |  |
    |  |- ShowA
    |
    |- StackNavigator
    |  |
    |  |- ListB
    |  |
    |  |- ShowB
```

`ListA` shows, as you might expect, a list of resources (type `A`). Pressing on one sets the state and navigates you to `ShowA` where you are viewing details about that specific resource.

`ListB` shows a list of resources (type `B`), and `ShowB` *also* shows a list of resources, however the resources are of type `A`. When pressing on one of these resources, you should be navigated to `ShowA`.

If on `ListA` I press and navigate to `ShowA`, that works perfectly.
If on `ShowB` I press and navigate to `ShowA`, that also works as expected.

However, if I first go to `ListA`, navigate to `ShowA`, then (without pressing 'Back' on `ShowA`) use the TabNavigator and go to `ListB`, then to `ShowB`, pressing on a resource opens `ShowA` but it's another instance of the screen placed on top of the stack. So when I press 'Back', instead of taking me to `ListA` as would be expected, it takes me to the previously opened `ShowA`.

I'm sorry if the formatting or explanation of this is inadequate. If anyone can help or if anyone needs more information please let me know and I'll do whatever I can.

Answer (score 0):

You should register two screens using the same component under different screen names. The structure should look something like this:

```
Tab:
  Stack
    "Tab1List"
    "Tab1Show"
  Stack
    "Tab2List"
    "Tab2Show"
```

Comment: That seems to be what I've already done. I only added the `A` and `B` to the `StackNavigator` for simplicity.